# sybase/isql 15.7 : query returns more characters than exists in table

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

table contains varchar(30) field

query:  select accID

Using isql/12.5, same query, same Sybase 15 database: isql query returns rows with 30 column field.

Using isql/15.7, same query, same Sybase 15 database: isql query returns rows with 60 column field.

Is there some sort of configuration issue here?

Thanks.
Lori

Answer (score 0):

How the values are displayed via isql does not affect the datatype of the individual fields, nor the value of the fields.  Just because isql has padded the column with extra characters, it does not change the value of the field, only the way it displays on the screen.  Isql pads fields for readability.

Comment: I think it is odd that isql will add extra padding to the file that is not being asked for.  If the field is 30 characters long, why would isql think that doubling this to 60 is a "good idea"? This doesn't seem like a good practice to me.  Now the lengths of the file are too long for no reason at all.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: ok...i got the answer from my IT person...has to do with 32-bit database on solaris and porting the data to 64-bit on a linux box.  mystery solved.  thanks for your answer.